# Vertx.io GET silently fails

Tags: java, vert.x, vertex

I'm writing a POC using vertx, looking for alternatives when we have to migrate Spring Web from 4.x to 5 to be java 9 compliant. 
I've written a simple client, just a GET towards a publicly available server just to get something working but it silently fails me.

```
    public List<String> pull() {

      Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

      HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions().setLogActivity(true);
      HttpClient hc = vertx.createHttpClient(options);
      hc.getNow(80, "http://sunet.se", "/",r -> {
        System.out.println("\n****** Handler called! ***\n");
      });
      return new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

This will silently fail and I cannot understand why.
As far as I can tell, I do exactly as in the examples given in the docs.
In desperation I fired up wire shark and according to WS, there is no actual call (when I use the browser WS captures that). So, it seems my call is never actually done. I don't get any exceptions or anything. Setting the log level to debug gives nothing noteworthy other than

```
Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn. Default: 128
```

And that should not fail the call. 
I've also tried using vertx.io WebClient but that fails also, in the same manner.

**UPDATE**
I've managed to get it to work but with a caveat.
As @tsegismont states in his answer, the protocol part of the URI shouldn't be there, that was not in the examples, I just missed it myself.
I ran my example as a stand-alone and then it worked.
My original example was run as a junit test (it's an easy way to test code and I usually try to write the test code first) and when it's run as a junit test it still doesn't work. Why that is, I have no idea. I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me how to get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getNow` variant you use expects the server host, not a URL. It should be:

```
hc.getNow(80, "sunet.se", "/",r -> {
  System.out.println("\n****** Handler called! ***\n");
}
```

If you found a snippet like this in the Vert.x docs it's a bug. Would you mind to report it?

Now a few comments.

1/ The `HttpClient` is a low-level client.

Most users should prefer the [Vert.x Web Client](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/)

Here's an example for your use case:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

client
  .get(80, "sunet.se", "/")
  .send(ar -> {
    if (ar.succeeded()) {
      // Obtain response
      HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
      System.out.println("Received response with status code" + response.statusCode());
    } else {
      System.out.println("Something went wrong " + ar.cause().getMessage());
    }
  });
```

2/ Create a single Vert.x and `WebClient` instance

Do not create a Vert.x and `WebClient` instance on every method call.
It wastes resources and is inefficient.