# Problems testing vertx http client code

Tags: java, junit, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I've got a strange problem that is an extension of [Vertx.io GET silently fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273538/vertx-io-get-silently-fails/49274883#49274883). When I run the code in junit, it fails (silently). The code cannot access the network. I've started a local server on 8080 but the code when run in the test cannot access, instead it just fails silently. 
This is very inconvenient, not to mention new to me, and I would like it to go away!

Comment: please post some code